# Javascript SELECT BOX options dependent on other SELECT BOX option selected

Tags: javascript, php

i have a problem. I wanted to do on my web page this thing:
1. i have select box like this

```
 <select name="firstbox" id="#firstbox">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

2. i have select box of which options are depending on first box, so if i choose in first box Option 1 i will have lets say this:

```
 <select name="secondbox" id="#secondbox">
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

and if i choose Option 2 i would have lets say

```
<select name="secondbox" id="#secondbox">
    <option value="8">Option 8</option>
    <option value="9">Option 9</option>
</select>
```

And in adition based on those two selection box i need one link that changes url depending on those two. So it would be IF option from #firstbox = 1, and secondbox=2  #link is first.html

```
<a href="first.html" id="link" >Show </a>
```

I dont know if its doable in javascript, or is it better and more smooth to make it with PHP and small database... But i still dont know in that case how to change link of that button... Hope someone has an idea.

Comment: you could use AJAX to show only the options you want in the second select box. And i guess the link only should be available, if both select boxes are manipulated, so you could add a `onchange="..."` to the second select box which calls a javascript function which creates or modifies the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, if you opt to use jQuery, of course you can use the `onchange` event. But first, you need to set a simple default values, wherein, it depends on what you select. Consider this example:

```
<select name="firstbox" id="firstbox" style="width: 100px;">
    <option disabled selected>Select Value</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<div id="select_boxes"></div>
<div id="link"></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var default_values = {
    "1": {"label": "first","values": [4,5]},
    "2": {"label": "second","values": [8,9]},
    "3": {"label": "third","values": [6,7]}
};

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#firstbox').on('change', function(){
        var current = $(this).val();
        $('#select_boxes').html('<select name="secondbox" id="secondbox" style="width: 100px;"></select>');
        var options = '';
        $.each(default_values[current].values, function(index, values){
            options += '<option value="'+values+'">Option '+values+'</option>'; // fetch options
        });
        $('#secondbox').html(options); // add options
        $('#link').html('<a href="'+default_values[current].label+'.html" id="link">show</a>');
    });

});
</script>
```

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Rnw4s7)

Comment: wow nicely done m8... That seconbox cannot be visible on start or? And btw what would code be if link should be different for combination of boxes. so box 1 option 1 and box 2 option lets say 4 link is different then box 1 option1 and box 2 option 5? If you get me... Thanks alot.. really good code

Comment: @Emanuel regarding the secondbox, you can just initialize an empty select box, in the current sample, upon change of the first select box, the second select element is dynamically created. so just add a new empty one, and you need to make a few tweaks, if you want a series of combinations, you're gonna have to change the default values to your liking.